# MySQL Inner Join Query Syntax error

Tags: mysql

I'm kind of a MySQL novice and can't figure out what is going wrong here. I have two tables. The left table is called Workouts. The relevant columns are `date` (type date) and `id` (type int).

The right table is called `Workout_locations` (relevant fields: `workout_id type int, and location_id type int`).

The join fields are `Workouts.id` and `Workout_locations.workout_id`.

All I want to do is get a table of two columns: `date` (from Workouts), and `location_id` (from `Workout_locations`). I need to only pull records from the `Workouts` table based on a couple of fields (the sql statement should make this clear).

Here is my sql syntax:

```
SELECT Workouts.date as date, Workout_locations.location_id as loc_id
FROM Workouts 
WHERE Workouts.pacegroup_id='9' AND (Workouts.date BETWEEN '2013-08-19' AND '2013-08-25') 
INNER JOIN Workout_locations ON Workouts.id=Workout_locations.workout_id"
```

But I get this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'INNER JOIN Workout_locations ON
>   Workouts.id=Workout_locations.workout_id' at line 1

I'm hoping that this is a very easy error to spot for someone who is experienced with this. Can anyone see it? Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `INNER JOIN` should come before the `WHERE`. I also don't think you needed the parens [around your `BETWEEN` clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between), but I doubt that it'll cause an error either way:

```
SELECT Workouts.date as date, Workout_locations.location_id as loc_id 
FROM Workouts 
INNER JOIN Workout_locations ON Workouts.id=Workout_locations.workout_id
WHERE Workouts.pacegroup_id = '9' 
AND Workouts.date BETWEEN '2013-08-19' AND '2013-08-25';
```

Also, though they *technically* let you get away with it, you should avoid using "date" as a selected column name (it's a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)).

You could do a bit of streamlining as well to make things a bit easier to read:

```
SELECT Workouts.date AS wo_date, Workout_locations.location_id AS loc_id
FROM Workouts w
INNER JOIN Workout_locations l ON w.id = l.workout_id
WHERE w.pacegroup_id = '9'
AND w.date BETWEEN '2013-08-19' AND '2013-08-25';
```

Comment: That seems to solve it. Yes, the parens are mostly for my own sanity. Thanks!